# Как лучше устроить взаимодействие между программами

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

Добрый день есть следующий вопрос: как лучше организовать взаимодействие между несколькими процессами на одной машине? Ситуация следующая: есть несколько написанных модулей системы на qt5. Одни модули отображают общую картину. Другие позволяют редактировать отдельные позиции (объекты). Нужно следующее взаимодействие в общем списке выбирается объект. Если программы для его редактирование не было запущенно, то запускается программа, а после этого ей дается сообщение на редактирование. Если же была запущенна, то просто отсылается сообщение на редактирование.

После редактирования программе со списком отправляется сообщение, что нужно обновить объект.

**Как проще всего организовать данную функциональность?**

Comment: Масса вариантов. Можно посмотреть на TCP/UDP, тогда и разнести на несколько машин все это можно будет.

Comment: если на одной машине, можно использовать QLocalServer, правда у меня были случаи что сообщения терялись, а вот QTcpSocket нормально работали.

Comment: Как проще реализовать - вопрос не корректный, так как определенного ответа на него нет - это дело вкуса каждого, для каждого свое "проще".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариантов это сделать есть несколько, все они подробно описанны в документации и собранны там в одном месте: [Inter-Process Communication in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html). 
И какой выбрать - дело вкуса и ситуации, и долгих прений :)
Мне например оптимальней всего пришелся `d-bus`

Comment: d-bus это Linux-only решение, так что автору не подойдёт — у него windows

Comment: Уже есть  d-bus и на винде.  на офф сайте пруф. И в qt как системе кросплатформенной реализуются только кросплатформенные инструменты. ( @ixSci Спасибо большое за правку ответа, мне с планшета не получилось красиво :))

Comment: Хм, действительно, появился какой-то порт на Windows. И как, нормально работает? А про qt и только кроссплатформенные решение — Вы заблуждаетесь. Той же d-bus реализации в Qt уже туча лет и раньше не было никакого порта на windows.

Comment: Работает хорошо :) а версию о том что на кутэ только кросплатформенные фишки - мне самой недвно В ответе писали люди с немалой репутаций :) это видимо из разряда городских легенд )

Comment: Наверное будем использовать D-BUS, если он заведется под windows

Comment: Заведется, вы ответ то пометьте верным, если он вас устраивает ) .

Comment: Есть еще один вопрос. Поднял dbus-demon для локальной сессии <listen>tcp:host=localhost,port=12345</listen>
nmap показывает, что на этом порте висит этот демон. Прописал переменную окружения DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS tcp:host=localhost,port=12345. dbus-monitor.exe говорит, что есть сервер. А из QT пробую подключиться и не дает выдает ошибку org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Disconnected. Подскажите в каком направлении искать мануалы?

Comment: @ЕфимовЕвгений задайте отдельным вопросом, вам больше людей сможет помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Так как вам нужно реализовать взаимодейстие в рамках одной машины, то самым лучшим вариантом будет использовать общую память. С помощью бустов вы можете реализовать такое общение без особо серьезных проблем. Пример:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   using namespace boost::interprocess;

   if(argc == 1){  //Parent process
      //Remove shared memory on construction and destruction
      struct shm_remove
      {
         shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
         ~shm_remove(){ shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
      } remover;

      //Create a shared memory object.
      shared_memory_object shm (create_only, "MySharedMemory", read_write);

      //Set size
      shm.truncate(1000);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region(shm, read_write);

      //Write all the memory to 1
      std::memset(region.get_address(), 1, region.get_size());

      //Launch child process
      std::string s(argv[0]); s += " child ";
      if(0 != std::system(s.c_str()))
         return 1;
   }
   else{
      //Open already created shared memory object.
      shared_memory_object shm (open_only, "MySharedMemory", read_only);

      //Map the whole shared memory in this process
      mapped_region region(shm, read_only);

      //Check that memory was initialized to 1
      char *mem = static_cast<char*>(region.get_address());
      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < region.get_size(); ++i)
         if(*mem++ != 1)
            return 1;   //Error checking memory
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Подробнее [тут](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html)

Comment: Хотя ответ и можно считать полезным, он, всё же — плохой. У человека Qt, зачем Вы приводите ему решение на boost? В Qt есть те же возможности, что представлены тут.

Answer (score 0):

Если фактор простоты реализации описанного в вопросе межпроцессного взаимодействия является ключевым, то можно взять для себя за основу негласное правило, заключающееся в том, что каждое отдельное "сообщение" должно редактироваться во вновь создаваемом отдельном процессе (даже одного и того же приложения-редактора).

При запуске процесса-редактора достаточно будет передать ему "сообщение" в виде аргумента командной строки посредством `QProcess`. Получить данные обратно можно будет через стандартный канал чтения, в который процесс-редактор и будет отсылать результат.

Минусы: запуск отдельного процесса-редактора на каждое сообщение, что в случае с "тяжёлым" редактором, а также многочисленностью одновременных редактирований может быть неприемлемо.

Плюс: наверное самый простой способ в Qt.

Comment: Не подходит автору, так как не всегда одно пиложение запускается из другого. Иногда второе уже запущенно.

Comment: @Mira , да, я знаю, потому и поставил первым словом в своём ответе: "Если".

Comment: К сожалению запускать отдельный процесс на каждую правку, слишком большая роскошь.